# Can I provide a custom icon for my custom LINQPad data context driver?

Tags: linqpad

I recently started writing [LINQPad data context drivers](http://www.linqpad.net/extensibility.aspx) for accessing various types of systems. Unfortunately every driver I write, uses the same "cog wheel" icon. This makes it harder to discern their type than if they'd have a type-specific icon.

Is there a way to provide a custom icon for a driver?

Comment: This is coming very soon... stay posted.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I just downloaded beta version 4.42.10 and now have custom icons for my custom drivers. Do you have any timeline as to when this version will get out of beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe wasn't kidding in his comment. The release notes for LINQPad Beta version 4.42.10 contain this:

> You can now specify a custom icon when writing Data Context drivers. Just include two files in your .lpx package: Connection.png and FailedConnection.png (the latter is applied if a data context is unable to load).

What the release notes don't mention (but is obvious once you check the existing icons) is that the icons needs to be 16x16 pixels.